# How to unify the Scoreboard class to have Team classes as members?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to be able to declare statements in int main() like:

```
Scoreboard s1; //assuming T1 and T2 as public members

s1.T1.setName("Dallas Cowboys");
s1.T2.setName("Houston Texans");

Scoreboard s2; //assuming T1 and T2 as private members passed as parameters accessed with setters and getters

s2.Team1().setName("Dallas Cowboys"); 
s2.Team2().setName("Houston Texans");
```

That what I have in my main but it currently throws an error of:

- No member named T1 in scoreboard
- No member named T2 in scoreboard

The second error comes from the second Scoreboard and throws exactly the same error but with the difference that instead of using T1, T2. It uses Team1(), Team2(). I tried changing their names to T1 & T2 but still its not working :/.

My scoreboard class pretty much just looks like this but I just can not figure out my problem:

```
class Scoreboard{
  private:
    Team T1;
    Team T2;
  public:
    Scoreboard(){
      T1.setName(""); 
      T2.setName(""); 
    }
    // Setters
    void setTeam1(Team team1) { T1 = team1; }
    void setTeam2(Team team2) { T2 = team2; }

    // Getters
    Team getTeamOne() const { return T1; }
    Team getTeamTwo() const { return T2; }
    // Print current data stored at Student on demand
    void showScoreboard(){
      cout << "SCOREBOARD CURRENT DATA" << endl;
      cout << "Team1                          Visitor" << endl;
      cout << " " << T1 << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" << T2 << endl;
    }
};
```

Do you guys have any idea of where my error comes from?

Comment: T1 and T2 are private in your class and thus you cannot just access them like `s1.T1`. And for `s2.Team()`, what are trying to do? You cannot just call a constructor of one class as a member function of another

Comment: Well, I tried to delete them from there and it still throws me the same error.

Comment: What error do you get specifically?

Comment: Okay, I've provided an example of how you can do this. See if that helps you. Do ask if something is still not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `T1` and `T2` are `private` members of `Scoreboard`, you cannot directly access them from the object `s1` of the `Scoreboard` class. Instead you have to use a setter to assign values ( an object of `Team` class in your case).

As you've already written a setter, `setTeam`, just create two teams separately and assign them to the object of Scoreboard class using it. Refer the code below for the example.

```
Scoreboard s1; 

// s1.T1 and s1.T2 will not be available here 
// since they are private in Scoreboard class

Team t1;
t1.setName("Team 1");

Team t2;
t2.setName("Team 2");

s1.setTeam1(t1);  // Assigning the Team t1 to s1
s1.setTeam2(t2);  // Assigning the Team t2 to s1
```

This should clear things up for you.

Comment: Yes I know how to use that but If I continue doing that it then tells me 'use of undeclared identifier T1 , T2' even after declaring it.

Comment: Where have I used `T1` or `T2` in this example?

Comment: main I'm assuming.

Comment: No, i meant, this code just above, it uses `t1` and `t2` and shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: This code was just to point you out that you were doing it incorrectly like this `s2.Team1().setName()`